# British Airways Fare Basis Code

Tags: tickets, bookings, fares, british-airways, fare-basis

Fare Class (or Fare Code) is the letter you see in your ticket reservation; the common ones are:

- `F` - First class
- `J` - Business Class
- `Y` - Economy Class

On British Airways however, I recently had a ticket with the fare code of `I`, what is this class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Club Europe/World (Discounted)](http://flyerguide.com/Booking_Classes_%28BA%29). (A Business Class 'flavour'):

[image: TSE37505 example]

Comment: If you can copy the code table to this answer, it would make it more permanent in case the link goes down.

Comment: it should be noted that this table is now out-of-date - economy discounted fares are currently awarded points at a heavy discount

Answer (score 0):

**I** is a discounted business class booking code.  Different airlines use the same booking codes for different purposes, but in general **J** is full-fare business, **D** is lightly-discounted business, and **I** is deeply-discounted business.  Likewise, **F** is in general full-fare first class, while **P** and **A** are discount first-class.  Coach has many more discount codes.